# Cashing Checks Via Photograph

Tags: check, personal-check

Recently I discover a great time saver. Rather than Fedexing my check to my bank in US, I simply photograph the check with IPhone and tada the check is deposited.

However I still have to have the check with me.

My friend have the same issue. He wants to send me money. He usually did that with paypal account. However, now my paypal is limited. It's not wise to send $3k-$4k via paypal anyway.

I propose that he scan his check, send it to me, I printed his check, then photograph again pretending I am photographing the real check.

I wonder if it's possible/legal?

The process of printing checks may seem like check forgery. However, there is nothing fraudulent. The money is indeed there and the guy really wants to pay me. It's more practical than sending the money via fedex to my house so I can "photograph" it.

Obviously it's not toward my best interest to commit fraud with this method given that I want my bank to trust me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not illegal. With respect to littleadv response, the printing of a check isn't illegal. I can order checks from cheap check printers, and they have no relationship to any bank, so long as they have my routing number and checking account number, they print. 
Years ago (25+) I wrote my account details on a shirt in protest to owing the IRS money, and my bank cashed it. They charged a penalty of some nominal amount, $20 or so for 'non-standard check format' or something like that. But, in fact, stupid young person rants aside, you may write a check out by hand on a piece of paper and it should clear. The missing factor is the magnetic ink. But, I often see a regular check with a strip taped to the bottom when the mag strip fails, proving that bad ink will not prevent a check from clearing.

So long as the person trying to send you the funds isn't going to dispute the transaction (and the check is made out to you, so I suppose they couldn't even do that) this process should be simple. I see little to no risk so long as the image isn't intercepted along the way.

Comment: I would have selected this as the answer if not because I want some second opinion. In any case what the bank see is a photograph of the check anyway. So things like magnetic ink will have effect whatsoever.

Comment: Oh ya, you can always order check from cheap check printers.

Comment: Right. In my long-winded, logical fashion, I built a case going from bank check to hand printed, to a photo. The magnetic strip was just a tangent. Thanks for the 'best answer'.

Comment: Hell, any time. The other answers got more votes though. I'll ask this somewhere else to make sure. Not a very common way. With this kind of info, paypal would go bankcrupt. I will ask for regular billpay.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm not sure you're right. Printing checks may very well be illegal, if it someone else's checks, if its not in the US, if its unauthorized, etc.

Comment: @littleadv - printing one's own check is surely legal. Printing someone else's? I make a distinction between a forgery, which of course is illegal, and printing a signed, endorsed check payable to you. I'm always open to new thoughts. You write a check, payable to me, sign it, scan it, email image to me, I photo-cash it. Which step broke which law?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I don't know, I'm not a lawyer, especially not in other countries.

Comment: @littleadv - I'm trying to understand the distinction you are making. If Jim simply photo-deposited the scan from his friend off his computer screen, would that change anything? (Although, from your answer below, it would be interesting to see if the scanning of the check revealed a light activated 'void' across it. That would sure render this thread moot.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I've lived in another country, not US, and it was illegal there to deposit copies of checks, only originals.

Comment: I do not think sending checks will activate void. I don't see it when photographing checks. Scan works like photograph.

Comment: @littleadv - "... it was illegal there to deposit copies of checks." When you make a deposit using a cellphone, what gets deposited **IS** a copy of the check. "Only originals" is sort of meaningless if the bank allows you to use a cellphone to deposit a photo of the check (or my bank allows me to deposit a check by scanning with a printer/scanner attached to my PC). Either way, what gets deposited is a copy of the check, not the original.

Comment: @KevinFegan notice that I said that you can do it because you can produce the original on demand. Have you noticed that? No? Then read again until you do.

Comment: @littleadv - you are instructed (by bank) that once the cellphone-photographed check has been posted to your account, you must destroy the original check after so many days (number of days will vary from bank to bank). The "proof" is then the scanned image that the bank has, just like any other check that is converted from paper to electronic.

Comment: @KevinFegan exactly the opposite. You're instructed **not** to destroy the check for **at least** certain amount of time - which is the time the bank needs to validate the check. When they tell you "keep the check for 45 days" what they mean is "if we ask for it within 45 days - you must be able to present it".

Comment: @littleadv - Ok, now it's your turn to read again... I am instructed to keep the original check (not destroy it) for so many days after the deposit has posted (certain amount of time), and then I am to destroy it, **THEN** (I assume this is to eliminate the possibility to deposit it again). In my case, it's 14 days after the deposit has posted to my account but as I said this will vary from bank to bank. The way you stated it ("...at least a certain amount of time..."), you could keep it for months or years, which my bank definitely **doesn't** want me to do (perhaps it's OK with your bank).

Comment: @KevinFegan again, I'll reiterate. You're instructed to **keep** the check for **at least** a given amount of time during which you **must** be able to present it when asked. What you do with it after that is up to you. I'm not sure what is the point you're trying to make with the fact that your bank suggest destroying, but it is irrelevant. I'm done with this discussion, please stop trolling me.

Answer (score 5):

It might be illegal for the very reason you stated: *The process of printing checks may seem like check forgery*. Banks in the US are allowed to do that, and the only condition under which you can do it with your iPhone (again, in the US) is the same as the one for banks: you can produce the original check on demand.

Of course, if the whole thing is legit and no-one is going to dispute the check (=no-one will demand the original from you), it might work (legal issues aside). It works in the US.

Beware of several things:

1. It might not work. Banks **can** demand the original. If you can't produce one on demand, especially if the transaction is reported as fraudulent, you may get into a lot of trouble.
2. Photocopying checks might not be legal in your jurisdiction (you're not in the US, you need to check local laws).
3. Photocopying checks may result in images that **cannot** be deposited (like the word VOID appearing all around). That doesn't usually happen when taking a snapshot with an iPhone, but it happens (seen that myself, when scanned checks for records) if you're scanning.
4. Deposit by scan/picture is usually limited to low amounts (I know that Chase limits it at several hundreds, I had troubles depositing $2K checks with them through the phone).

Comment: Are you sure they can demand an original?  My bank specifically tells me to destroy the check after 14 days.  But +1 for the limit; mine limit with schwab is pretty low too.

Comment: I also feel the low value checks could be cashed by the bank without proper verification. For higher limits, for security reasons, the bank may not process the transaction.

Comment: McCrhister, IIRC you should keep it until the statement posts, at least

Comment: After depositing a check remotely, my bank instructs me to keep the original, write 'processed electronically' on it on the front, then destroy it after 45 days. Your bank will surely provide instructions, probably similar instructions.